# An Array of Related Data. Maybe array of ojects

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript but comming along good enough. 
i have a project and i need to store alot of related data.

e.g. Full name, DOB, age, height,etc.

my idea after seeing `objects` was to have an array of object.
that's the idea but i found no good information online that would help me execute this.

basically were my idea came from was structs in `C` that i treat as records.
so i'd have and array of structs in c and the rest is self explanitory.

but i was to store the related data together like how i'd store data with a struct array.

please keep in mind unknown amount of entries

EDIT:
i found a simpler method that seem to work compare to the complicated things i'm getting as a starter.

```
var array= [];

function dosomething(){
  for(var i=0;i<whateverNumber;i++){
   array[i] = {name: "Delano", age:19, so on so forth}
  }
}
```

Comment: array of structs = array of objects in JS. Example: `[{a:1},{b:2}]`

Comment: i can't say i understand your example. it's a bit too short

Comment: You haven't provided any code your working with either. An array is just, for example, `var x = []`. Then you can put whatever you want in there. `var y = {age:31,name:'Tom'}; x.push(y)`. It's hard to believe that you've found no good information online about how to store objects in an array in JS.

Comment: i think i'm understanding alittle more.

Comment: do i have to initialize the values of the properties?
by the way tom. thanks its a little clearer now.

Comment: You don't have to initialize anything. AN object is just a key-value store where the keys are strings. `var x = {}; var y = {name:'Tom'}; var z = {name:'Tom',age:31};`. Once an object is created `var x = {}`, it can (generally) be modified at any time: `var x = {}; x.name = 'Tom'; `. All this information is readily available on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: Use Javascript objects exactly the way you would use C structs.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a variable and then start pushing the object into your array something like this

```
var obj = {id:1,age:26,name:"jhon doe"};
var obj2= {id:2,age:24,name:"jhon doe2"};
var arr = []
arr.push(obj,obj2)
console.log(arr)
```

and to remove the last object from your array of object simply use `arr.pop()`